# How to change distribution method from private to public?

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, app-store-connect

So I have an app that has been verified but set to private for app distribution. We no longer wish to use Apple Business Manager to distribute the app but make it publicly available.

I understand that we must create a new app in the App Store Connect portal to do this. But have the following questions;

1. The Bundle ID must be different.  Is it sufficient for me to change this in Xcode, clean and build project and use the edited bundle ID?
2. The SKU must be different - is this only set when creating the app in the App Store Connect; nothing to be set in Xcode?
3. Can the remainder of the app information be left as is i.e. logo, name, description, pricing etc. ?
4. Is there anything that I am missing or should be aware of before creating a new app for public use?

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "private for app distribution". Is that available on AppStore? Or you are distributing on Testflight?

Comment: Not TestFlight.  And yes, available via App Store Connect.  Setting it to private allows us to distribute the app to specific clients using Apple Business Manager but regular users will not see the app in the store. Basically, I want to create a new app in App Store connect - rename the old app to something like "MyApp_old" and the new app to "MyApp", change the bundle ID and submit it for review but set the distribution to public this time.

Comment: @Aleksendar mark accept my below answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding solutions

Comment: Did not get a chance to come back to this.  I'll see if I get time later and create the new app in App Store Connect and confirm your answer has all the necessary details.  Will mark as resolved upon confirmation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do as you said. I explained clearly what you need

1-) Yes, you should change on your xcode from General tab, clean and build. If you have an developer account, xcode will do the rest.

- From **Signing & Capabilities** tab, you should check **Automatically manage signing** option and choose your team firstly

2-) Correct. The SKU number will added from App Store Connect.

3-) Yes, It can be same.

4-) Also you have to provide screenshoot at least 3, description and privacy section from app store connect.